# Defining object type after a reduce function based on generic key types

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have this helper function I'm using to transform an array of objects with many keys into a dictionary with key value pair where the key is the value of one of the keys and the value is the value of another key on the same array element.

```
 export const getMappingDictionary = <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(objectsToMap: T[], key: keyof T, value: keyof T) => {
  return objectsToMap.reduce((prev, cur) => ({ ...prev, [cur[key]]: cur[value] }), {}); 
};
```

So an array like:

```
[ {name: "chair", id: 1, description: "omg a chair"},
 {name: "table", id: 2, description: "thats a nice table"},
 {name: "lamp", id: 3, description: "so bright"}]
```

will become

```
const mymap = getMappingDictionary(myarray, "name", "id") = 
{ chair: 1, table: 2, lamp: 3 }
```

However after I've tried playing around with the typing I cannot get it correctly.

Maybe I'm overdoing stuff and it has even a nicer solution.

The motivation behind this method is that I can build enums on the fly by either using static objects in my code (and then usage is `mymap.chair`, and my IDE can even provide me hints when typing `mymap dot`) or dinamically by plugging it into an async function that retrieves some objects from a remote API (using it like `mymap["chair"]` knowing that the chair key is always going to be present but id, or other properties I want to map may change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with the `reduce` unless there's a good reason why you can't use `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const v: Record<string, number> = 
    Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ name, id }) => [name, id]))
```

A reusable, generalized version of this (using selector functions, not strings) might be:

```
const createLookupObject = <T, V>(
    items: T[],
    keySelector: (x: T) => string,
    valueSelector: (x: T) => V
): Record<string, V> => {
    const contentEntryLookup: Record<string, V> = Object.fromEntries(
        items.map((ce) => [keySelector(ce), valueSelector(ce)])
    );
    return contentEntryLookup;
};
```

so here you would:

```
createObjectLookup(data, x => x.name, x => x.id);
```

For posterity, the `reduce` version of the above looks like this:

```
const createLookupObject_Reduce = <T, V>(
    items: T[],
    keySelector: (x: T) => string,
    valueSelector: (x: T) => V
): Record<string, V> => {
    const contentEntryLookup: Record<string, V> = items.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [keySelector(curr)]: valueSelector(curr) }), {})
    return contentEntryLookup;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3jMCC2ApgFwwBEwAFggJYBOZANDDXKQIzNyETB00AHKDXCkyIfAHMYKKrQYwAvowBQOPETHIARgBtCTFmxgAmLjz6Dho8lGpQIM3DWCEYO-WSWr1BEuV0CAUNWUgBmc15+IREwMQgQGG1+SUooL0UAXRUVUEhYPkIkQgAZEBAAawBXAQB5bQArQmBYdAAeABVmADUAPgAKFQBIGihCfAhSDoxM1SGKwgBPAGVCfRaQOlJ+gA8pgEo0XphofjBJOYA3BF0qwlX1qE3tvZgOw9Rj7pV90gAlZqbOBtU40c49Y6fGBYYZ5aAwPJjMBQACiyLoizKlRq-0BdGBoPBMD6aBg9SaLQAdAAzOgSNFQfg8QZDEZjCaU-AIAT9fquD7HDALFZrZpPOh8wj7ZjXW73UUbCX8zL7Yb7ADcwzohCgVToYAR4CRqPRmPK1QEmsUmty4Hhl3YpMKxSxFvJYv6iGQzB2RxgO0pGkIPr9AdYqttkBA+kpuhAkn6ZAdTAdEbhBW1LvNNXdLQA+gC4FVXKTOhCWaNxpM3jM5sKHmLnjBdgc-YSLsNZXcG4qXq2od9fjAAaB8SDGWCLsTIccYUN04bkYRkQyMa6ccO8QSJ0SSehKxztUXXLyEMBgMxgHq6ALmzhKQ+zxfMPWFeK+df9plSF35Y9Nh+dA3ko0rQooqpDNqur6ouxqrma2KWio1o5AulwmE6mZjOudSNGKBaEMehCekgCAhlCAZBuRxxhnAaZ2tGhCxvGiboYY6H7EAA)

Answer (score 1):

Just learning some more advanced TS and found both the question and the answers very interesting. So I challenged myself to create a more generic version which:

1. allows mapping over string\number\symbol values
2. allows mapping over values constrained with union type (see last example)
3. by default maps to a source object (but allows also extracting any given property or create anything you want using source object)

Here it is:

```
const createLookupObject = <
        T, 
        TKey extends keyof T, 
        TKeyValue extends T[TKey] & (string | number | symbol), 
        TValueExtractor extends (i: T) => unknown = (i: T) => T
    >
(
    items: T[],
    key: TKey,
    valueExtractor?: TValueExtractor
): [TKeyValue] extends [never] ? never : Record<TKeyValue, ReturnType<TValueExtractor>>  => {
    const contentEntryLookup = Object.fromEntries(
        items.map((ce) => [ce[key], valueExtractor ? valueExtractor(ce) : ce])
    );
    return contentEntryLookup;
};

/* EXAMPLES */

const permissions = [
    { "Id": "ACCESS", "Order": 1, "Granted": true },
    { "Id": "EXPORT", "Order": 2, "Granted": true },
    { "Id": "DELETE", "Order": 3, "Granted": true }, 
]

// Record<string, number>
const lookup = createLookupObject(permissions, "Id", i => i.Order)

/*
 Record<number, {
    Id: string;
    Order: number;
    Granted: boolean;
}>;
*/
const lookup2 = createLookupObject(permissions, "Order")

/*
 never - boolean cannot be used as indexer
*/
const lookup3 = createLookupObject(permissions, "Granted")

/*
  Lookup by a key defined with union type
*/
export type LocaleId = 'sk' | 'cs' | 'en'

export interface LocaleInfoRecord {
  isoName: LocaleId,
  nativeName: string,
  isLoaded: boolean,
  localeData?: {},
}
const locales : LocaleInfoRecord[] = [
  { isoName: 'sk', nativeName: 'Slovenčina', isLoaded: false },
  { isoName: 'cs', nativeName: 'Čeština', isLoaded: false },
  { isoName: 'en', nativeName: 'English', isLoaded: false },
]

// Record<'sk' | 'cs' | 'en', LocaleInfoRecord>
const localesLookup = createLookupObject(locales, 'isoName')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=41&ssc=1&pln=59&pc=61#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-r1Zqe32YGxe6U4Ty4QBuHl1YOh9PgTM13P5tpwHekAyXsgAelvMC9oAkg0+3x+ImBoOQfNIqdg5zNOeLK1PUjRAe0xZ9FAbyIKgGBYDg8gWCIaBJmgpZpMgG6kHeABUJhPj6gxfmCSAiFQPJMGwb6-JephYUgbCkcg9GUL4eSMGwnTNOc9RgJeBgUpeeG3pUOAARBcCeCBdQNAgZ6QT00Gwcg6CYNgkDyIxtA4fhJgOk6uIALQwDxsL8emqj0rAYLUhAGgwMouDfJIyzIGQonidUMCAQWcCZLJYEKVJUH9Kp8EaUhdAcf4ukVKQt4EWEilwGZizKDA0owJIOzfI5DJCgAFtSYCaYEEYIJ5YmkCscA4rAUCVTATTABcCBMCyADkEAtF1EJdcAED9YCXUEl1CV1Q1MDfOoSA7Bq+ite19BgDsIBERIyZhBgIAAHLKCgCBsMtfFMAqYANGgToHUdNG1r8CoYE0yiSFxZm8fxCqAW1fHRA0yg6tQRhkAY3lpj97W4CdIC-R1a0bd6EjiiyJBhDQu23cdMA9X1n5XTdh3Y11fCAU6YCALCA3zKF1qEQC9b1sAt5wOSEIwYxA+1E2wg3DfjUDXQgWM84AMIAIIAhoAC5dtMzfTICvRoTMXKzIPo7LXN3Tj4384Lws49mPznBgRUy898uMzAzMq6E5S4YlD6bb6uMjTjQ0u2NYAy6d8PrY7v7-r5sNQ6lQXyalYUwZDfEQCIXWY0TXVwkAA)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of possible solution:

```js
type Elem = Record<string, string | number>;

export const getMappingDictionary =
    <T extends Elem, Key1 extends keyof T, Key2 extends Exclude<keyof T, Key1>>(objectsToMap: T[], key: Key1, value: Key2) =>
        objectsToMap.reduce((acc, elem) => ({ ...acc, [elem[key]]: elem[value] }), {} as Record<T[Key1], T[Key2]>)

const arr = [
    { name: "chair", id: 1, description: "omg a chair" },
    { name: "table", id: 2, description: "thats a nice table" },
    { name: "lamp", id: 3, description: "so bright" },
];

const mymap = getMappingDictionary(arr, "name", "name"); // error
const mymap1 = getMappingDictionary(arr, "name", "id"); // Record<string, number>
const mymapw = getMappingDictionary(arr, "id", "name"); // Record<number, string>
```

I assume, that second key can't be equal to first
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAogGygWxgXhgJSgYwPYBOAJgDwDOIBAlgHYDmANDBdfTAD4w0CuyARlAIA%20ANzBgUAB4RCIGPhoUYdKCACyAQwgRadACJUcIKnhoaCYdMBg2YJACowpIKDSJl4SZEwDSUMACMTpIubh4A1v54AGYw9r7%20AEzBoe7wkjgI3ERQJJFgMXEJgUJCABR4fABWuCBk9niaEABccQDaALpM%20a1%20gUwAbhpZUL1JAJToQta2s5U1RvWNWgB0BFBE3DhQZWUaODhMUF6TaEIwZQDeMCu3%204cwbccobfkdHa3PyG1DIx0wAF9xkxLgCYBoPNh8MQHG0%20gEuu0%20okOkJxuIFEpzAR0I8ZjZrmZkKMYAAiHAACw0VAIpKYVCIrQCTByZBw1AgxlMrVJeGQdHB8ipNNJgIY%20JghI0xJ5IA0fCQdJgDNaiRZUDZHK5NFlVLqgpohlgcoVUFFAPFsylMrJCGlECVKpgAGZ1ZqqJyTDqyWQ8DA%20NQ6BSQObxR0xMBMXJkGBkFpcSp1FodPQDEYveYwHsCAQmKSiWa8wXSeMRDAAPTlpw5wiR0xKGNxiBBDCJpop-SGbWZ7O5snFvMMktlytYXCEUgsXRMHj8QTTKMwRtaADuCdU7d0ae7Fl7g6ISvz0rNpYrVahE5Is4EfYoNPo02AQA)